# Create a Subclass from a String

Tags: python

Using Python I want to achieve the following.

```
fruit = Fruit()
fruit.add_item('apple')
fruit.apple.add_color('red')
fruit.apple.add_taste('sweet')
fruit.add_item("lemon")
fruit.lemon.add_color('yellow')
fruit.lemon.add_taste('bitter')
```

i.e. I need to create a subclass from a string. This seems like a it might be a common design pattern. How would this be achieved?

Comment: Why do `apple` and `lemon` need to be subclasses? They look like mere instances of a type to me here. `setattr(self, name, Fruit())` would achieve that without having to generate a new class every time..

Comment: I think what you would like to do is create a fruit like this, instead:`lemon = Fruit()`, then do `lemon.color = yellow`

Comment: The builder pattern can clean this up a bit, but mostly you need to rethink things in more OO terms.  `lemon` and `apple` should be *instances* of `Fruit`.

Comment: The example is maybe poorly thought out. It is mostly the pattern i'm after. Dict/List will do this for sure but for this piece of code i very deliberately want to use OO. The structure i'm actually trying to get away from is list or list of dict (and many level deeper with long text entries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like you actually need to create any subclass.  Rather:

```
class OneFruit(object):
    def add_color(self, color):
        self.color = color
    def add_taste(self, taste):
        self.taste = taste

class Fruit(object):
    def add_item(self, name):
        setattr(self, name, OneFruit())
```

This simple code meets your example.  If what you want is something very different, please make a suitably different example and edit your question accordingly!-)

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Just gave it a try. This is what i'm after.